# Not able to install Statistics::Basic on RHEL5

Tags: rhel5, perl, rpm, cpan

I am trying to install the perl module Statistics::Basic::Mode on a RHEL 5 system and am having issues.

I have tried MCPAN and RPM.  Here is the result of running

sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell > output2.txt

install Statistics::Basic::Mode

[Link to CPAN results](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/407477/)

When I tried to install it using rpm I used the following:

[Link to site where I got the rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/perl%28Statistics::Basic::Mode%29)

I ran the following:
sudo rpm -i perl-Statistics-Basic-1.6601-2.el5.rf.noarch.rpm

I get the following:
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(Number::Format) >= 1.61 is needed by perl-Statistics-Basic-1.6601-2.el5.rf.noarch

so I tried to install Number::Format, but the response I get is that it is up to date.  I am not sure where to go from here.  Any advice would be great.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is Number::Format at the correct version? It's possible that the version in your repos is too low. It's also worth making sure that Number::Format is in your @INC. If it's not, you could add the path to it into $PERL5LIB, and try installing again?